# Chrome doesn't render span in div properly

Tags: css, google-chrome

When a span is nested in a div with a different background there's a small gap above and below it. FF doesn't render like that.

Here is the html :

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div style="background-color:magenta">
   <span style="background-color:cyan">Nested</span>
  </div>  
  <div style="background-color:cyan">Can you see that magenta line ?</div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone has experienced this ?

Thanks
PS: I'm running chrome 5.0.307.9 beta under Xubuntu 9.10

Comment: Just because FF does it one way, does not mean it's the right way. My god, look a IE! They did pretty much, _everything_ wrong for what ... Over 10 years now? People considered that the standard for a very long time. (It was the dark ages of the internet.) Granted FF does not come close to IE, but still. Everyone reads the rules differently, you _should_ redefine every css property to what you expect it to be to make your environment consistent between browsers. If you have a question go to the W3C and see what it SHOULD be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the default `line-height`. Browsers vary on how they define the default line-height ("normal") but many do make it a touch more than 1em (the default height of a span). Try explicitly setting the line-height to 1em:

```
<span style="background-color:cyan;line-height:1em;">Nested</span>
```

or

```
<div style="background-color:magenta;line-height:1em;">
```

If you want to use a line-height greater than 1em, you'll need to mark the span `display:inline-block` in order to allow its background color to fill the height of the line rather than just the 1em of the inline span:

```
<div style="background-color:magenta;line-height:2em;">
  <span style="background-color:cyan;display:inline-block;">Nested</span>
</div>
```

Comment: One of the bad things the W3C did. Almost everything is left up to the interpretation of their standard, and no default is given for everyone. I'm glad to see W3C setting stings right with HTML5 and fixing some of their major issues with the standard as a whole.