# Why does space between label and span add height to div (only Chrome)?

Tags: html, dom, webkit, css

I have this problem on a clients site. I've minified the issue and seen that the problem is a single space that got in between a closing label and a closing span. Compare these two:

```
<div class="outerdiv">
 <span class="outerspan"><span class="innerspan"></span>
 <input type="radio" value="true" checked="checked"><label>Label</label></span>
</div>


<div class="outerdiv">
 <span class="outerspan"><span class="innerspan"></span>
 <input type="radio" value="true" checked="checked"><label>Label</label> </span>
</div>
```

In Chrome, the height of the outer div differs alot and the difference is based on the margin of the label. Not in FF. It seems to be related to inline-block. However, I can't seem to understand the numbers and Chrome developer tools doesn't seem to help me a bit getting them straight.

Here's a fiddle that displays the heights:

http://jsfiddle.net/3hHk5/6/

Update:
Safari adds height too, but not as much as Chrome. Numbers seem very random to me.

Clarification:
I want to understand *why* the height is different between FF, Chrome and Safari and where the numbers originate from. The fix for my particular problem could just be to remove the space :)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346383/chrome-doesnt-render-span-in-div-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **float:left** from **innerspan**, seems to work in your fiddle. I dint quite get the purpose of span/float here. Using float removes the element from document flow. If you want to align the text to left, use text-align:left.

**EDIT:**

White spaces in HTML affects all the inline elements and it specifically affects the height. You have used display:inline-block on outerspan. And if you notice, there is space before the closing span tag in your second DIV. That is the reason for extra height.

```
<div id="space" class="outerdiv space">
<span class="outerspan"><span class="innerspan"></span><input type="radio" value="true"     checked="checked"><label>Label</label> </span>
</div>
```

You will notice that if you remove the space before the closing span tag, it affects the height. So either using display: block would ignore the white space or remove the spaces in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'm sorry if I was unclear, but I want to understand why the height differs between FF, Chrome and Safari and where the numbers originate from.

Comment: Thanks again, but what I don't understand is 1) Why is there no extra height in FF? 2) Why is there no extra height in Chrome if I replace the space with "FOO"? 3) Why is the height different between FF, Chrome and Safari, the later both being webkit? Is this related to default line height? 4) How is the height calculated? No numbers in the css can add up to the actual height of the div.

Comment: It is strictly browser specific! When there is a space in inline elements, the space wraps into a new line in some browsers and the height of the new line is affected by the line-height setting of the browser. Some browsers simply ignore the white space for inline elements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer! I still feel I need to know more about this though. I thought the state of modern browsers was better than this.

Comment: Thank you! You might want to read about "white-space" and how the values are treated in different browsers. If you set white-space to some value other than the default value which is "normal", you will again notice that the extra height is removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
.outerspan {
    display:block;
}
```